# .net I always get negative answer when use random

Tags: c#, .net, math

In this code I always get a negative answer.Why? 
I was hoping to always get different answers because it's random. I'll be greateful for any help!

```
Random random = new Random();
int a = 10;
int cycle = 1000;
while (cycle != 0)
{
    a += random.Next(-1, 1);
    cycle--;
}
```

Comment: You'll get 0 or 1 with equal probability

Comment: Read the documentation of [Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_): The second parameter is **exclusive** which means you are only generating numbers between -1 and 0 which will sum up to be some negative value.

Comment: `random.Next(a, b);` will return a number n such as `a <= n < b`. Upper number is **exclusive**. `random.Next(-1, 1);` gives `-1` or `0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `Next(-1, 1)` you'll get `-1` or `0`. Never `1`, because:

The lower bound of `Random.Next` is ***inclusive***.

The upper bound of `Random.Next` is ***exclusive***.

To achieve your goal, change the range from `[-1, 1)` to `[-1, 2)`

```
random.Next(-1, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a look at the documentation for [`Random.Next(int, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_):

> #### Parameters
>
> `minValue`
>
> The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
>
> `maxValue`
>
> The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. `maxValue` must be greater than or equal to `minValue`.
>
> #### Returns
>
> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to `minValue` and less than `maxValue`; that is, the range of return values includes `minValue` but not `maxValue`. If `minValue` equals `maxValue`, `minValue` is returned.

So you're asking for a number which is

1. Greater than or equal to `-1`
2. Less than `1`

The possible numbers you'll get at `-1` and `0`. Notice that if you add lots of `-1`'s and `0`'s together, you'll never get above `0`<sup>1</sup>...

If you wanted to get the numbers `-1`, `0` and `1`, you need to use:

```
random.Next(-1, 2);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Barring integer overflow

Comment: @Cid Pedant :) Added a footnote.

Comment: "maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue". But if they are equal but maxValue cannot be chosen, then what happens? For instance `random.Next(0,0)`?

Comment: @Noceo you'll get only 0. Considering the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_), *"If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned."*

Comment: @Cid I would still argue that it's an invalid statement. `minValue` is inclusive, `maxValue` is exclusive, yet they are allowed to be equal to one another? That doesn't make sense :-). It's not that much of a practical problem though.

Comment: @Noceo I suspect the designers decided there was no point in *banning* `Next(0, 0)`, and instead decided to return something more useful in this case. It can't be changed without breaking backwards compat though, so it is how it is